# Can we have two DBContext(code first and database first) in an asp.net Blazor project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an `asp.net Blazor` project with CodeFirst `DBContext` of `Entity frmaework7.x`

I have another library project with Database first `DBContext` of `Entity Framework 6.x`

Now, I have added the project reference of the library project to `Blazor` project.

I added the service references for both of the DbContext in the Program.cs file of the `Blazor` project as below:

```
 //THIS IS THE CODE FIRST DB CONTEXT EF Core
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CodeFirstContext>(opt =>
 {
   opt.UseSqlServer(configuration["CodeFirstDatabase"]);
  });

  //THIS IS THE DBFIRST DB CONTEXT EF6.X
  string DBFirstDatabase= 
  builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBFirstDatabase").ToString(); 
  builder.Services.AddScoped(provider => new DBFirstEntities(DBFirstDatabase));
```

Defined the following new `constructor` in the DBFirstEntities `class`. It inherits the `DBContext class`.

```
       public DBFirstEntities(string  connectionString):base(connectionString)
        {

        }
```

Now facing the following error:

> #### An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> `UnintentionalCodeFirstException`: The context is being used in Code
> First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for
> either Database First or Model First development. This will not
> work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code
> that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or
> Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection
> string is included in the `app.config` or `web.config` of the start-up
> project. If you are creating your own `DbConnection`, then make sure
> that it is an `EntityConnection` and not some other type of
> `DbConnection`, and that you pass it to one of the base `DbContext`
> constructors that take a `DbConnection`.

Is there any way to use 2 DBContext with different approaches?

Comment: @SirRufo Yes, because it wasn't well formatted when pasting here. but for your convenience, I have removed the image and posted the exception there. I hope now you can understand and provide some solution instead of pointing out the imperfections and checking the profile timeline.

Comment: There is a good reason why you should not post text as a screenshot: an image can not be indexed as plain text. And to me the formatting (after my edit) is good enough

Comment: Does your connectionstring contain the full edmx information?